# Prove limit of relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, and let $R = \{v : f(v) = 0 \}$

Want to show that $\forall v \in R$ where, in a neighbourhood of $v$:

- $f$ is defined
- $f$ is differentiable
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ne 0$

That

$$\lim_{u \to v \atop u \in R} \frac{v_y-u_y}{v_x - u_x} = \frac{-\left(\frac{\partial f(v)}{\partial x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\partial f(v)}{\partial y}\right)}$$

However - can't use the Implicit Function Theorem. Been trying to solve this for a few days now.

Comment: To me this screams of a clever application of the mean value theorem, but I don't see it right now...

Comment: Although, thinking about it, any argument involving the mean value theorem would need $f$ to be continuously differentiable instead of differentiable, in order to arrive at the derivatives at position $v$.

Comment: Hmm, and if $f$ where continuously differentiable? I don't see the mean value theorem yet.